# jwplayer getDuration works in chrome console, but not in C# with IJavaScriptExecutor

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jwplayer

I am having trouble with jwplayers getDuration command. My current best guess is that it may be a translation issue with C#'s javascript executor. Thank you everyone.

This is the failing C# code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = ( IJavaScriptExecutor )Driver;
                    executor.ExecuteScript( "jwplayer().seek(jwPlayer().getDuration());", "" );
```

This is the Javascript that works in Chrome Console.

```
jwplayer().seek(jwPlayer().getDuration())
```

This code works.

```
executor.ExecuteScript( "jwplayer().seek(45);", "" );
```

This code fails.

```
executor.ExecuteScript( "jwplayer().getDuration();", "" );
```

The error I recieve is:

```
unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

(Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.153)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Is there a way a link can be provided in this case?

Comment: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#controls
This is the link to the API. Aside from that, I cannot disclose any further information. Sorry.

Comment: I can't debug this really...this is our site, and this works fine, since our player is running in a webpage here. We never really tested it in C#.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help. It really shouldn't make a difference being in C# because I simply execute them as Javascript commands. I'm thinking it might actually have to do with how the executor interprets and returns. I may be in need of some special syntax or such.

Comment: Yes, theoretically it shouldn't make a difference, but you never know with these sorts of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is problem with executor interprets and returns.

But I too faced some issue while trying to get time duration in `Jwplayer` and found out that if you `jwplayer().getDuration` works properly only if used inside events such as `onReady` , `onPlay` and `onTime`.
If you try to use it outside that before player gets ready it will not return anything.

To understand how it works I have created four `Jwplayer` with and without `events` and

you can experience the behaviour [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/6YyXH/20/) in

jsfiddle -   http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/6YyXH/20/

Also below is same code used in JSfiddle

```
jwplayer('player').setup({

            file: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
            primary:'html5',
            stretching: 'exactfit',         
            autostart: true,

        });     

jwplayer('player2').setup({

            file: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
            primary:'html5',
            stretching: 'exactfit',         
            autostart: true,

        }); 
jwplayer('player3').setup({

            file: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
            primary:'html5',
            stretching: 'exactfit',         
            autostart: true,

        }); 
jwplayer('player4').setup({

            file: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
            primary:'html5',
            stretching: 'exactfit',         
            autostart: true,

        });
var time1  = jwplayer('player').getDuration();
$("#player_time1").text(time1);//wont show anything at all

jwplayer('player2').onReady(function(){
var time2  = jwplayer('player2').getDuration();
$("#player_time2").text(time2);//will show time duration as -1

});

jwplayer('player3').onPlay(function(){
var time3  = jwplayer('player3').getDuration();
$("#player_time3").text(time3);//will show time duration as -1
// but if click on play and pause it will show correct time
});

jwplayer('player4').onTime(function(){

var time4  = jwplayer('player4').getDuration();
 var time45 = jwplayer('player4').getPosition()
$("#player_time4").text(time4);//it works 
    $("#player_time45").text(time45);//it works 
});
```

Hope it gives some helpful information :)